# SAN, BROCADE and WINDOWS SERVER, filesystem trouble

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, storage-area-network, brocade, zoning

I'm building a DR infrastructure using 4 Servers, 2 Eternus Fujitsu and Brocade 300 Switches.
All configurations are done: zoning, paths, LUNs and so on.

I have a situation: When I create a file from one server, none of the others three see the file. Neither refreshing or rescanning disks.

On the events panel I see:

"A corruption was discovered in the file system structure on volume G:.
The exact nature of the corruption is unknown.  The file system structures need to be scanned online."

Can someone help me to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you're using regular NTFS without any form of cluster file management? If so the issues you're facing are simple - NTFS on it's own is not a 'cluster-aware filesystem', each server thinks it has complete control of every disk block and will therefore not play nicely with others.

What you need to do is use Windows Clustering/MSDTC to manage the file locking or use a third-party solution such as Veritas Storage Foundation for Windows. Anything else will cause immediate corruption as you mention.